# "TypeError: Undefined is not a function" (Passing an object from a dependency) in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

So I'm trying to learn RequireJS for work. It seemed easy enough, but then I ran into a problem. How do I pass on an object from within one of the dependencies?

The code below returns "TypeError: Undefined is not a function" for the new variable. I tried logging the typeof GoogleMap, but it also returns undefined.

What is the correct way of doing this?

**Main.js**

```
require(['test', 'geo', 'googlemaps'], function (GoogleMap) {
        var map = new GoogleMap();
});
```

**googlemaps.js**

```
define(function() {

        function GoogleMap(){

           var i = 0;
           var userMarkers = [];

           var map = {}

           this.initialize = function(lat,lng){
                map = getMap(lat,lng);
           }

           var getMap = function(lat,lng){
               var asldOptions = {
                     zoom: 4,
                     center: new google.maps.LatLng(59, 18),
                     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 };

               map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), asldOptions);

               return map;
           }
        }
    }
);
```

**Edit:** I should add that it works fine when i remove the 'define' line at the top and the corresponding brackets at the bottom of googlemaps.js.

Comment: the function you pass to `define` in googlemaps.js needs to return something. You probably just want to return the `GoogleMap` function (which, incidentally, does not need to be named).

Comment: @DavidMcMullin, Could you give me an example of how such a return statement would look? return GoogleMap; isn't working, but it feels like i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(['test', 'geo', 'googlemaps'], function (GoogleMap) {
```

change that to

```
require(['test', 'geo', 'googlemaps'], function (test, geo, GoogleMap) {
```

and try again.

Your GoogleMap is not mapped to googlemaps script, but to test. it is in the order which you specify your dependencies.

Either way, my previous answer still stands. That is how you should be returning the function in your googlemaps.js file.

Hope that helps.
Suj

Answer (score 1):

```
define(function() {

    var GoogleMap  = function(){

       var i = 0;
       var userMarkers = [];

       var map = {}

       this.initialize = function(lat,lng){
            map = getMap(lat,lng);
       }

       var getMap = function(lat,lng){
           var asldOptions = {
                 zoom: 4,
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(59, 18),
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             };

           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), asldOptions);

           return map;
       }
    }

    return GoogleMap;

  }
);
```

Comment: That's a no-go, compadre. Sorry.

Comment: require(['test', 'geo', 'googlemaps'], function (GoogleMap) ===> GoogleMap is mapped to test not to googlemaps. That is your problem. Change it to require(['test', 'geo', 'googlemaps'], function (test, geo, GoogleMap)  and try again